# svg viewbox scaling issue

Tags: svg, coordinates, viewbox

I've a question about svg's viewbox, in my opinion it's like a window on an infinite svg plan, and its boundaries are set in the viewBox attribute of the svg element. It represents the rectangle between the 2 coordinates in the svg plan. So a viewBox of "0 0 1000 500" shows the window between (0,0) and (1000,500) of the svg plan.
And when I make viewBox (2000, 0, 3000 500) i see the window of (2000,0) and (3000,500). x and y scaling is unmodified: in both cases i'm displaying 1000 * 500 units of the svg plan.

But apparantly i go wrong some where. I'm experimenting with animating the viewbox to emulate some kind of ticker display, leaving the y coordinates untouched but changing the x coordinates (without changing the actual number of units displayed) but that goes wrong. Somehow my y-scaling changes.
In a modern browser you can verify [yourself](http://www.stretchsketch.com/tekst.html) (pull the slider to change the viewBox).
What did I miss in the SVG specification?

Comment: The viewbox is set as "min-x min-y width height" opposed to "min-x min-y max-x max-y"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the [preserveAspectRatio](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute in the SVG specification. It forces the aspect ratio of what you see in the viewbox to be preserved by default. Sounds like what you're after is preserveAspectRatio="none"

Comment: Hmm none of the possible values is giving me the desired result. I think I'd want something as xMidYNone. With "none" the y scaling is ok but the x scaling goes terribly wrong. I can solve it by animating the startpoint of the path, but I'm a kind of curious to solve it via the viewbox.